# How add header and footer to all pdf in a folder

Tags: pdftex, header-footer, pdf, pdfpages

I have following file called `addfooter.tex` to add header and footer in a pdf file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\fancyfoot[RO]{\url{https://mydomain.com}}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\url{https://www.facebook.com/mydomain}}
\fancyfoot[CO]{\thepage}

\fancyhead[LO]{\url{http://bit.ly/mydomain}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\url{https://test.mydomain.com}


  \includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}},pages=1]{ee.pdf}
  \includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},pages=2-]{ee.pdf}

\end{document}
```

This will create a file called `addfooter.pdf` with required header and footer. But I need to add header and footer to all my file in a folder. How to do it using a shell script or something like that?
I am using pdflatex command.

Comment: I think you need to draw the header and footer with tikz

Comment: Can you give the instructions?

Answer (score 1):

- Use `\usepackage` rather than `\RequirePackage`, the latter is intended for package and class files
- Make sure `hyperref` comes last of loaded packages.
- You are missing a `}` in `\fancyhead[RO]{\url{https://test.mydomain.com}`.

Following code should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\url{http://bit.ly/mydomain}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\url{https://test.mydomain.com}}

\fancyfoot[RO]{\url{https://mydomain.com}}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\url{https://www.facebook.com/mydomain}}
\fancyfoot[CO]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{example.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question was how to add footer and header to all pdf in a folder with single step

Comment: @MonsoonMalabar Sorry for missing the folder information, you can writte a python script to do this: get all file path -> generate `filename.tex` file -> call latexmk or pdflatex to generate pdf file.

Comment: @MonsoonMalabar Or you can write a makefile, anyway not by tex.